# How to get define a variable within a function without reseting it

Tags: python, function

I'm currently making a music quiz. I have come across a problem and don't know how to solve it. I'm using a variable called wrong. It is supposed to be an int, if I define it at the begin of the code it won't transfer into the function. And if define it in the function it resets.

Comment: pass the variable as function parameter and return it at the end of the function

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please remember to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the function without first creating the variable, or not, Python can handle either case.

```
def music(answers):
    # Where answers is [(user input, correct answer) ...]
    wrong = []
    for i in answers:
        if i[0] == i[1]:
            pass
        else:
          wrong.append(i)  
    return wrong

wrong = music(answers)
```

Or if you want to pick up where you left off with previous values for answers and wrong:

```
wrong = [(previous values, previous answers) ...]

def music(answers, wrong = []):
    # Where answers is [(user input, correct answer) ...]
    wrong = []
    for i in answers:
        if i[0] == i[1]:
            pass
        else:
          wrong.append(i)  
    return wrong

wrong = music(answers, wrong=wrong)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Make it global. When you define wrong at the beginning like this

```
wrong = 10
```

Just call global inside the function and it should use the initialized variable

```
def your_function(): 
    global wrong
    wrong_temp = wrong
    #use wrong_temp however
```

I would also take a look at this link. It looks like this might solve the question you are asking, but it is also helpful to understand how global variables work. [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: Function names are usually written like `your_function`

Comment: Word, bro. always got to remember good coding practices @CharlesLandau